# Pathing finding in Chess? 2d array searching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path-finding, chess

I currently am working on a Chess app. I've created an array which is the `board` in this board is `Sqaure` components that hold a `Piece` and a position which is an `[x,y]` coordinates of where it is located.

I'm starting to work on the first baby steps of implementing movement into the project.

My question is, given a current location as an array like this `[1, 0]` how can *path find* towards a target position `[2,5]` I know this isn't a possible chess move, I just want to be able to stimulate any movement before I start working on stipulations. My current function is pretty bare bones, but I wasn't sure if my explanation was good enough

```
const calculateMovement = (board, piece, x , y, index) => {
    // board is a global array, holding all position -
    // board = [[0, 0], [1, 0]]
    // Current Location of the piece I want to move

    // x is row
    // y is col
    // how to get every piece between the currentLocation and wantedLocation
    let currentLocation = [x, y]
    let wantedLocation = [8, 8]
  }
```

Comment: TBH I'm not sure why you would need any path finding in chess, it's not like there are barriers to navigate, it's a 2-dimensional, open grid. Perhaps you can explain the use case more clearly. Seems you would rather need to know a specific piece's valid moves and simply check if the new coordinate is occupied or not.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836721 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602763 for two different ways of representing the chess board and movement of pieces.

Answer (score 0):

In general, pathfinding can be achieved using a Breadth First Search. [Wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) This is a good starting point and will be especially helpful for complex pieces like the Knight. The next step might be to look at the A* pathfinding algorithm. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

A good resource for building a project like this is the [Chess Programming Wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Main_Page)