# How to execute all squares the knight will stop on along the way while going from the one position to another?

Tags: javascript, breadth-first-search, knights-tour

I've been doing Knights Travails project, and I just can't come up with a solution like I want: (should show the shortest possible way to get from one square to another by outputting all squares the knight will stop on along the way), I can do that it will execute the lenght of the path, but it's not what I want.

```
function knightMoves(start, end) {
    const directions = [[1, 2], [1, -2], [-1, 2], [-1, -2], [2, 1], [2, -1], [-2, 1], [-2, -1]];

    const visited = new Set();
    const queue = [start];
    const path = [start];

    while(queue.length) {
        const square = queue.shift();

        if (square[0] == end[0] && square[1] == end[1]) return path;

        for (let d in directions) {
            const possibleX = square[0] + directions[d][0];
            const possibleY = square[1] + directions[d][1];

            if (!visited.has(directions[d] && possibleX >= 0 && possibleX <= 8 && possibleY >= 0 && possibleY <= 8)) {
                visited.add(directions[d]);
                queue.push(directions[d]);
            }
        }
    }

    return path;
}

console.log(knightMoves([0,0],[1,2])); // [[0,0],[1,2]]

// knightMoves([0,0],[3,3]) == [[0,0],[1,2],[3,3]]
// knightMoves([3,3],[0,0]) == [[3,3],[1,2],[0,0]]
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602763 for some inspiration...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Knight Travails game in question, but if the general gist of the game is "Given a knight on one square, and given a destination square, output the shortest sequence of moves needed to reach that square" then I believe the Uniform Cost Search algorithm (a variant of Dijkstra's shortest path) is your best bet.

The Wiki page provides pseudo-code for how to implement it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Practical_optimizations_and_infinite_graphs